# Standardize variables using dplyr [r]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I would like to standardize variables in R. I know about multiple approahces how this can be done.
However, I realy like using this approach bellow:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars

df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(value = value - mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)
```

For some reason this approach does not work since I am not able to return the data to the original format. Therefore, I would like to ask for advice

Comment: Why not simply `as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, function(x) x - mean(x)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you first make data in long format and then return back to wide, neither why you don't prefer `scale(df)` which is computationally much faster.

Anyway, if you really want to use a code similar to the one you like, you need to perform a further `unnest` action in order to return the data to the original format.

```
df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(value = value - mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 32 x 11
#       mpg    cyl    disp    hp    drat       wt   qsec     vs     am   gear   carb
#     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1  0.909 -0.188  -70.7  -36.7  0.303  -0.597   -1.39  -0.438  0.594  0.312  1.19 
#  2  0.909 -0.188  -70.7  -36.7  0.303  -0.342   -0.829 -0.438  0.594  0.312  1.19 
#  3  2.71  -2.19  -123.   -53.7  0.253  -0.897    0.761  0.562  0.594  0.312 -1.81 
#  4  1.31  -0.188   27.3  -36.7 -0.517  -0.00225  1.59   0.562 -0.406 -0.688 -1.81 
#  5 -1.39   1.81   129.    28.3 -0.447   0.223   -0.829 -0.438 -0.406 -0.688 -0.812
#  6 -1.99  -0.188   -5.72 -41.7 -0.837   0.243    2.37   0.562 -0.406 -0.688 -1.81 
#  7 -5.79   1.81   129.    98.3 -0.387   0.353   -2.01  -0.438 -0.406 -0.688  1.19 
#  8  4.31  -2.19   -84.0  -84.7  0.0934 -0.0272   2.15   0.562 -0.406  0.312 -0.812
#  9  2.71  -2.19   -89.9  -51.7  0.323  -0.0673   5.05   0.562 -0.406  0.312 -0.812
# 10 -0.891 -0.188  -63.1  -23.7  0.323   0.223    0.451  0.562 -0.406  0.312  1.19 
# ... with 22 more rows
```

---

#### EDIT

In order to use the most up-to-date `tidyr` functions, you should consider substituting `gather`, which is retired now, with [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) as in the following code. The obtained result is the same.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(value = value - mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

Comment: This is complex and computationally expensive solution to a trivial problem.

Comment: I know that it is computationally intensive, in fact I wrote "why you don't prefer scale(df) which is computationally much faster". I was following the OP's indications as he/she said "I know about multiple approaches how this can be done. However, I really like using this approach below"

Comment: Like I write in original questing - I know that there are many more sophisticated ways how to do so. Main Idea of this approach is that everyone e.g. students can *see* the formula where we subtract the mean and devide by standard deviation

Comment: @Petr so is my approach what you were looking for? Did it solve your issue?

Comment: scale(df) is is wrong. scale() expects a matrix. It will sort of work if your df happens to only contain numerical data, but this is rare, and the returned object is no longer a data frame. Trivial counterexample: scale(iris).

Answer (score 8):

According to the current documentation, you should be using [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)-based syntax to perform operations on a desired subset of columns. You can use `everything` to select all columns or use [any other available qualifier](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html). You should only use `group_by` verb if your desire is to perform operation on groups. `group_by` is not right choice for selecting variables.

```
mtcars %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . - mean(.)))
```

As for the actual standardisation or any other operation you want to apply to the subset of columns you can use:

> **.fns**   Functions to apply to each of the selected columns. Possible
> values are:
>
> - `NULL`, to returns the columns untransformed.
> - A function, e.g. `mean`.
> - A purrr-style lambda, e.g. `~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)`
> - A list of functions/lambdas, e.g. `list(mean = mean, n_miss = ~ sum(is.na(.x))`

So for `scale` you can do:

```
mtcars %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale))
```

or with additional arguments

```
mtcars %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale, center = FALSE))
```

## Side notes

As you can see from `?scale` documentation, the function returns matrix. In case of the examples above, you will get matrix with one column if this bothers you, you can do:

```
mtcars %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric),  ~ scale(.)[,1]))
```

### Comparison

```
>> mtcars %>%
...     as_tibble() %>%
...     mutate(across(where(is.numeric),  ~ scale(.)[,1])) %>% 
...     glimpse()
Rows: 32
Columns: 11
$ mpg  <dbl> 0.15088482, 0.15088482, 0.44954345, 0.21725341, -0.23073453, -0.33028740, -0.96078…
$ cyl  <dbl> -0.1049878, -0.1049878, -1.2248578, -0.1049878, 1.0148821, -0.1049878, 1.0148821, …
$ disp <dbl> -0.57061982, -0.57061982, -0.99018209, 0.22009369, 1.04308123, -0.04616698, 1.0430…
$ hp   <dbl> -0.53509284, -0.53509284, -0.78304046, -0.53509284, 0.41294217, 
...
>> 
>> 
>> mtcars %>%
...     as_tibble() %>%
...     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale)) %>% 
...     glimpse()
Rows: 32
Columns: 11
$ mpg  <dbl[,1]> <matrix[32 x 1]>
$ cyl  <dbl[,1]> <matrix[32 x 1]>
$ disp <dbl[,1]> <matrix[32 x 1]>
$ hp   <dbl[,1]> <matrix[32 x 1]>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is heplful:

```
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
```

You need a column that uniquely identifies each row:

```
df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number(), value = value - mean(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

You'll probably want to add back rownames to the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number(), value = value - mean(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Comment: Why might this be preferred over the top-voted answer? Can you offer an explanation?